# Localized urls in vue router not working and returning an error

Tags: vue-router, vuejs3

Trying to add a language prefix to the url with vue-router, but its returing an error with the message : `Uncaught Error: Missing required param "locale"` I'am trying to add routes that support language prefixs like en, de, nl, fr and so on...

I do see that I am using child routes which I actually dont need I guess...!

```
example.com/en/users
example.com/nl/users
example.com/fr/users
```

**routes.js**

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: "/",
        redirect: 'en'
    },
    {
        path: '/:locale',
        //path: '/:locale?', // this will work but it wont render the component
        name:'locale',
        component: {
            template: '<router-view />'
        },
        children:[
            { path: 'welcome', name: 'dashboard', component: page('Dashboard.vue'),
            },
            { path: 'users/index', name: 'users.index', component: page('Users/Index.vue'),
                children:[
                    { path: 'create', name: 'users.create', component: page('Users/Create.vue') } 
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

**router.js**

```
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes,
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    next();
})
```

Comment: what about `path: ':locale',`

Comment: Uncaught Error: Route paths should start with a "/": ":locale?" should be "/:locale?".

Answer (score 0):

You can get this error in Vue 3 if your component has `<router-link>`s on it that are missing the locale param.

For example, if DOM markup such as this appears:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'dashboard' }">
    Dashboard
</router-link>
```

change it to:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'dashboard', params: { locale: 'en' } }">
    Dashboard
</router-link>
```

The error can stem from any component that is trying to load. For example, you might have a `TopNavBar.vue` component that renders along with your intended component, so check that.